# Shopware 6 - AuthControllerDecorator is deprecated

Tags: php, symfony, shopware, shopware6

I am currently developing a Shopware plugin to showcase the login page from the register page. The implementation is functioning correctly.

However, I have encountered an issue where Shopware indicates that the Auth Controller has been made internal and is no longer accessible. I am seeking an alternative class that can be utilized for this purpose.

Could you suggest an alternative class that can be used in place of the Auth Controller?

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);
...

/**
 * @RouteScope(scopes={"storefront"})
 */
class AuthControllerDecorator extends AuthController 
{
    private AuthController $decoratedAuthController;
    private AccountLoginPageLoader $loginPageLoader;
    private AbstractSendPasswordRecoveryMailRoute $sendPasswordRecoveryMailRoute;
    private AbstractResetPasswordRoute $resetPasswordRoute;
    private AbstractLoginRoute $loginRoute;
    private AbstractLogoutRoute $logoutRoute;
    private StorefrontCartFacade $cartFacade;
    private AccountRecoverPasswordPageLoader $recoverPasswordPageLoader;
    private SalesChannelContextServiceInterface $salesChannelContext;

    public function __construct(
        AuthController $decoratedAuthController,
        AccountLoginPageLoader $loginPageLoader,
        AbstractSendPasswordRecoveryMailRoute $sendPasswordRecoveryMailRoute,
        AbstractResetPasswordRoute $resetPasswordRoute,
        AbstractLoginRoute $loginRoute,
        AbstractLogoutRoute $logoutRoute,
        StorefrontCartFacade $cartFacade,
        AccountRecoverPasswordPageLoader $recoverPasswordPageLoader,
        SalesChannelContextServiceInterface $salesChannelContextService
    ) {
        $this->decoratedAuthController = $decoratedAuthController;
        $this->loginPageLoader = $loginPageLoader;

        parent::__construct(
            $this->loginPageLoader = $loginPageLoader,
            $this->sendPasswordRecoveryMailRoute = $sendPasswordRecoveryMailRoute,
            $this->resetPasswordRoute = $resetPasswordRoute,
            $this->loginRoute = $loginRoute,
            $this->logoutRoute = $logoutRoute,
            $this->cartFacade = $cartFacade,
            $this->recoverPasswordPageLoader = $recoverPasswordPageLoader,
            $this->salesChannelContextService = $salesChannelContextService
        );
        
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/account/login", name="frontend.account.login.page", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function loginPage(Request $request, RequestDataBag $data, SalesChannelContext $context): Response
    {
        /** @var string $redirect */
        $redirect = $request->get('redirectTo', 'frontend.account.home.page');

        $customer = $context->getCustomer();

        if ($customer !== null && $customer->getGuest() === false) {
            $request->request->set('redirectTo', $redirect);

            return $this->createActionResponse($request);
        }

        $page = $this->loginPageLoader->load($request, $context);

        return $this->renderStorefront('@Storefront/storefront/page/account/login/index.html.twig', [
            'redirectTo' => $redirect,
            'redirectParameters' => $request->get('redirectParameters', json_encode([])),
            'page' => $page,
            'loginError' => (bool) $request->get('loginError'),
            'waitTime' => $request->get('waitTime'),
            'errorSnippet' => $request->get('errorSnippet'),
            'data' => $data,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Storefront controllers should not be decorated. If you want to add data to the page's template [listen for `AccountLoginPageLoadedEvent` and add extensions to the page](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/storefront/add-data-to-storefront-page#adding-data-to-the-storefront).

If you want to implement custom logic, e.g. on the actual login procedure, you should [decorate the corresponding store-api](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/store-api/override-existing-route) route `Shopware\Core\Checkout\Customer\SalesChannel\LoginRoute` instead, which is [intended to be decorated](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/4e2c56e81aa3a3c3ed58d9d39a9cb24bbf2dbeed/src/Core/Checkout/Customer/SalesChannel/LoginRoute.php#L44).